# Trying to get a cell to return blank if other cell is blank and if not + 1 to the result

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Question is same one I have in the title. It's been kind of head scratching. The formula I'm trying to use is `=IF(ISBLANK(A11),"",A11+1)` it works fine when the cell has a value in it but shows #!value if the cell is empty

I'm trying to get it to add  + 1 to a cell if the above cell has a value and to leave blank if it doesn't

Comment: Great, this fixed it for me. I didn't know "" populated a cell thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cell containing the empty string `""` is not blank. You have several options here, including:

```
=IF(A11="","",A11+1)
```

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A11),A11+1,"")
```

```
=IFERROR(A11+1,"")
```

```
=IF(LEN(A11)=0,"",A11+1)
```

Comment: Another possibility would be to use len() for the string length in A11.